# Error Calling PayPal Classic API Service

Tags: c#, paypal, wsdl

I am trying to pull down transaction from my PayPal account.  I made a successful call in the sandbox environment but cannot replicate that in live.

I have a C# console app (targeting framework 4). The service I have added is: `https://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl`

Here is my code (obviously only proof of concept so far):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new PayPalService.PayPalAPIInterfaceClient())
        {
            var credentials = new PayPalService.CustomSecurityHeaderType
            {
                Credentials = new PayPalService.UserIdPasswordType
                {
                    Username = "MyUsername",
                    Password = "MyPassword",
                    Signature = "MySignature"
                }
            };




            TransactionSearchReq request = new TransactionSearchReq();

            request.TransactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();


            request.TransactionSearchRequest.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12);

            request.TransactionSearchRequest.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

            TransactionSearchResponseType transactionSearchResponseType = client.TransactionSearch(ref credentials, request);

        }

    }
```

Endpoint

```
            <endpoint address="https://api.paypal.com/2.0/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="PayPalAPISoapBinding" contract="PayPayService.PayPalAPIInterface"
            name="PayPalAPI" />
```

When I make the call (last line of code) I get an error:

```
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://api.paypal.com/2.0/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
```

I have searched for answers but not found anything to solve the problem.  All I need to do is download the transactions no other functionality is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that you're sending the request to the correct endpoint?

- SOAP Certificate Method: https://api.paypal.com/2.0/
- SOAP Signature Method: https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/

More details here:  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/

Update:  It looks like the endpoint is indeed your problem.  Your code is using Username, Password, and Signature, but then you're setting the endpoint to the Certificate endpoint instead of the signature endpoint.

Comment: Yes I am fairly sure the endpoint is correct.  I have added it to the post.

Comment: Ok, so you're using a certificate then?  Have you installed the SSL certificate and configured it with the PayPal account correctly?  The signature method is a lot easier to get working.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough!! I had tried both endpoints in desperation (cert and sig) but neither worked.  Then I created a new project copied all the code (sig endpoint) and it worked second time (after adding the version number).  Spot on and thanks again.